# xmlhttp.responsetext result cannot appear in div using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am quite new using jquery. My problem is that why the xmlhttp.responseText cannot show in the div that I assign. I try using the alert and the alert successfully showing the result. I am using .blur() function on textbox to pass the textbox value so it can access php page to search in the database equal the textbox value.

this is how the view of the input looks like

```
<tr>
<td>
  <div align=center>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='section' name='section[]' style='font-size:11px'>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div name='desc' align='center' class='desc' style='width:100px;font-size:11px;'></div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
  <div align=center>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='section' name='section[]' style='font-size:11px'>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div name='desc' align='center' class='desc' style='width:100px;font-size:11px;'></div>
</td>
</tr>
```

There are more than two rows here but i just show you at least two row. I want to select database equal the value in the section input using blur() and put the result in the desc div just in the same row.

here is the function in js file

```
$('.section').blur(function(){
var getdesc = function(key) {
  if (key.length==0)
  { 
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.desc').html('');
  }

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      var feedback = xmlhttp.responseText;
      alert(feedback); //alert success showing the result
      $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.desc').html(feedback); 
      //the result didn't show in the desc div
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getsectiondesc.php?q="+key,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
getdesc($(this).val()); 
});
```

And this is the inside of getsectiondesc.php

```
<?php
  include "config/koneksi.php";
  $key = $_GET['q'];
  $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productx WHERE section='".$key."'");
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($search);
  if ($result>0){
    echo $result['product'];
  }
?>
```

I already try to pass the value of the section input directly to the desc div on the same row and it works. I am quite confused about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Also... HOLY MOTHER OF SQL INJECTIONS PLEASE DONT PASS $KEY STRAIGHT INTO A QUERY WITHOUT SANITIZING IT OR ITS GONNA BE BAD NEWS BEARS! http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: @ArunPJohny thank you for the link. I will study more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery can simplify your AJAX work for you quite a bit -- try something like the following:

```
$('.section').blur(function(){
  var section = this;
  $.get("getsectiondesc.php?q="+key, function(data) {
    $(section).parent().parent().next().find('.desc').html(data);
  });
});
```

I think where you might be tripped up though is in your interpretation of "this." When you reference "this" inside an `XMLHttpRequest` it will refer to the `XMLHttpRequest` not the `$('.section').blur()` that originally spawned the request. You'll have to save that context in a variable if you want to use it inside.

Comment: Wow seriously how come I didn't realize it until now. Thank you Darius and really thank you for the simplified code you recommended. It is working. oh and I am still experimenting the code so i'm not yet include the PDO. Thank you for the warning @Darius